# How to count the articles and place each in a list

Tags: python

I have a text document, that is composed of multiple articles separated by the token < NEW DOCUMENT>

I would like to place every article in a list

so for example if we have a txt file:

> < NEW DOCUMENT> Hello world Hello World < NEW DOCUMENT> Early Bird
>   Early Bird
>
> I would like List1 to be : Hello world Hello World
>
> List2 to be: Early Bird Early Bird

Now I do not know how many lists I need to create, so first I would need to count the token < NEW DOCUMENT>.

Second I would like to place every article in a list.

here is my program

```
#program 1

textFile = open("docs.txt" , "r")
lines = textFile.read()


count = 0

#count how many articles there are
for line in textFile:
    if line.strip() == '<NEW DOCUMENT>':
        count = count + 1


#place articles in lists





textFile.close()
```

I am getting 0 for count, and I am not sure how to start putting them in lists

Comment: Does `<NEW DOCUMENT>` appear in a line all by itself, or can there be other text along with it, on that line?

Comment: no it does not appear by itself it is attached like this :
<NEW DOCUMENT>A state weight inspector

Comment: The `==` operator tests for equality. I think you want to use the `in` operator to tests for containment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this text document isn't gigantic, and assuming you want a list of the form `['Hello world Hello World', 'Early Bird Early Bird']`:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    print([item.strip() for item in myfile.read().split('< NEW DOCUMENT>') if item])
```

If you want nested lists of the form `[['Hello', 'world', 'Hello', World'], ['Early', 'Bird', 'Early', 'Bird']]`:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    print([[myitem for myitem in item.strip().split(' ')] for item in myfile.read().split('< NEW DOCUMENT>') if item])
```

Comment: the text is gigantic, every <NEW DOCUMENT> is actually about 4 to 5 lines. there are about 25 article or document.

Comment: How gigantic is gigantic? That aspect is in terms of memory usage, so as long as it's less than a few hundred MB it should be fine. If `< NEW DOCUMENT>` has the same text each time, you could open the file in a text editor and replace all instances of it with a more compact term, like `'< NEW DOCUMENT>'`. `splitlines()` takes more memory, but the memory-efficient alternative is to loop over the lines, which works a lot better if it doesn't need to check something that spans multiple lines.

Comment: it's 498 kb so I guess it's fine. but the thing is I need to be able to store each article in a list. Here this stores all of them in one list. The reason I need each in a list is because I am creating a search engine for that document and I want to be able to pull out every single article alone. I need it more like List1 = ["Hello world Hello world"] and list2 = ["early bird early bird"]. That is just a simple example

Comment: If you need something like `["Hello world Hello world"]`, use this answer's first code sample but use `[item.strip()]` instead of `item.strip()`, which will put the string into a list. However, a list that only contains one element isn't generally very useful. Can you provide more context for why you want to do that? If you want each word to be an element of a nested list, use this answer's second code sample.

Comment: I want to store two types of data in two different data structures.  In one, you will have a dictionary that stores single words as the key with the value as the set of documents (numbers) that the word appears in. In the other data structure, you will store the actual text of the documents, so that you can display it for the user when they ask.  I want to use a list for the second data structure.

Comment: so the question to this post is I want my program to read in the documents from the file and number each document starting with 1 (the first document in the file is document 1, the second is document 2, etc.).

Comment: It sounds like you want something along the lines of `a = {'hello':[0,2], 'bird':[0,1]}`, with `b = ['hello bird', 'bird word', 'hello world']`, which would allow `for item in a.get('hello'): print(b[item])`, resulting in `'hello bird'` `'hello world'`. If you want something else, please add some clarification to your original question.

Comment: assuming I want to do it like you mentioned in your response,  '['Hello world Hello World', 'Early Bird Early Bird']' How would I access the first document in your list "Hello world hello world". Because I am creating a search engine where at the end of the day after grabbing every document and putting it in a list I need to be able to access it again

Comment: Please check my new question as it is more detailed

Comment: That's the whole point of lists: storing and retrieving related data. Access element `i` in list `b` with `b[i]`. Read the Python documentation on lists. Anyway, you would have to do that even with single-element lists, as `b = ['hello']` would require you to enter `b[0]` to access `'hello'`.

Comment: yes but this is not working. and I want to access Hello world Hello world and not just hello

Comment: Yes that is it ! it is including \n inbetween words when it prints it why do you think so?

Comment: Are you using the `print()` function or are you merely sending the strings to the Python interpreter? If you do something like `>>> 'hello\nhi'` you'll see `'hello\nhi'`, but `>>> print('hello\nhi')` results in `hello` on one line then `hi` on the next.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73634/discussion-between-mozein-and-tigerhawkt3).

Answer (score 1):

If the token appears on a line, with nothing else beside it:

```
newDoc = "<NEW DOCUMENT>"
listOfDocumetns = [[]]
with open('path/to/text/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == newDoc:
            listOfDocuments.append([])
            continue
        listOfDocuments[-1].append(line)
```

If the token appears on a line, with other text beside it:

```
newDoc = "<NEW DOCUMENT>"
listOfDocumetns = [[]]
with open('path/to/text/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        line = line.strip()
        if newDoc not in line:
            listOfDocuments[-1].append(line)
            continue
        while line:
           left, _, right = line.partition(newDoc)
           listOfDocuments[-1].append(left)
           listOfDocuments.append([])
           line = right
```

Comment: this does not work. the token does appear on the same line. And I want to be able to pull out every document at the end. so if I need List 1 I need to be able to pull it out