# Printing in which list or dictionary the word is located in

Tags: python, list, search, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a text file that contains the following:

```
<NEW DOCUMENT>
Look on the bright 
side of Life.
<NEW DOCUMENT>
look on the very, dark
side of the Moon
<NEW DOCUMENT>
is there life
on the moon
```

And I am trying to create a python script that can split this into multiple "documents" and then search through them, if I search for the word moon then it should tell me that it's found in 2nd and 3rd document. After searching for help, I managed to get it to print out the lines that it's finding the words in but it's not printing out what document it's in (I am trying to implement that but it's not working out that well with me).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here's the code so far:

```
def main():
    docs=[]
    with open("ap_docs2.txt") as f:
        lines = f.read().split("<NEW DOCUMENT>")[1:]
        for x in lines:
            docs.append(x.strip())
        numOfDocs=len(docs)
        docs1 = map(str.lower, docs) ## Convert list to lower case for search
        print (docs)
        print("Number of Documents:",numOfDocs)

    search = input("Enter search words: ")
    for x in docs1:
        if search in x:
            print ("{} found in:\t {}".format(search,x))

main()
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your `docs1` and `search` element for which its not showing the document name.

Comment: Possible repeat of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29218137/how-to-count-the-articles-and-place-each-in-a-list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you're wanting? I simply print the index of the matched line in the documents.

```
def main():
    docs=[]
    with open("ap_docs2.txt") as f:
        lines = f.read().split("<NEW DOCUMENT>")[1:]
        for x in lines:
            docs.append(x.strip().lower())
        numOfDocs=len(docs)
        print (docs)
        print("Number of Documents:",numOfDocs)

    search = input("Enter search words: ")
    for x in docs:
        if search in x:
            print('Found in document %d' % (docs.index(x) + 1))

main()
```